# Preimage of a cyclic group under the canonical epimorphism is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$\pi:G\twoheadrightarrow G/X$, $X=\langle x\rangle \subset G$, $A=\langle aX\rangle \subset G/X$, $x,a\in G$, $x\neq e$, $a\neq e.$

$\pi:g\mapsto gX$.

$G$ is finite, abelian.

I want to show that $\pi^{-1}A$ is cyclic.

I assumed naturally that $a$ would generate $\pi^{-1}A$ if it is cyclic. So I tried to show that $\exists n$ such that $a^n=b$ for every $b\in\pi^{-1}A$.

Pick any $b\in \pi^{-1}A.$ then $\pi b\in A\implies bX\in A$. So $bX=a^iX$ for some $i$.

Thus $bx^k=a^i$ for some $k$.

$\implies x^k=b^{-1}a^i\implies e=x^{km}=b^{-m}a^{im}$, where $m=|X|$.

$\implies b^m=a^{im}.$

But I think I can't just take $m$-th root on both sides.

How to proceed from here?

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, **not** `<` and `>`

Comment: You cannot show that $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is cyclic, because in general it need not be. For example, take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, $X=\langle (0,1)\rangle$, and $A=\langle (1,0)X\rangle$. Then $\pi^{-1}(A) = G$ which is not cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we replace $G$ by $\pi^{-1}(A)$ then your problem is the following: Suppose that $X$ is a cyclic subgroup of $G$ such that $A=G/X$ is cyclic. Show that $G$ is cyclic. As mentioned in the comments this is not true in general.

However, it is true if $gcd(|X|,|A|)=1$. You can prove it as follows: First use that (by the assumption) there is an element $g\in G$ which maps to a generator of $A$ and has order $|A|$. Then consider the order of $gx^k$, which is $|X|\cdot|A|$ for suitable $k$ (again use here that $gcd(|X|,|A|)=1$).

$G$ can always be of the form $X\times A$ which is not cyclic if $gcd(|X|,|A|)\neq1$, so the statement does not hold in general.

A more structural view: We are interested in the central extensions of the form
$$1\longrightarrow X\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow1,$$ which are in bijection with the second group cohomology $H^2(A;X)$. In case that $A$ and $X$ are cyclic this group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{|X|}/|A|\mathbb{Z}_{|X|}$. In case that $gcd(|X|,|A|)=1$ this group is trivial, so $G=X\times A$, which is cyclic (in this case). In the other cases the group is not trivial and there are several possibilities for $G$.